# haskell: cd command does not work in shake/command library

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

For some reason I cannot make `cd` command work in `shake/command` Haskell library. It thinks directory I called with `cd` does not exist even though it is present in the filesystem.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
dataDir = "data"

data Settings = Settings {
  url :: String
} deriving (Eq, Show, Generic, JSON.ToJSON, JSON.FromJSON)

settings :: String -> Handler Settings
settings subfolder = let 
  gitPath = dataDir ++ "/" ++ subfolder ++ "/git/.git"
  in do
    pathExists <- liftIO $ doesPathExist gitPath 
    -- Stdout pwdOut <- liftIO $ cmd ("pwd" :: String)
    -- liftIO $ putStrLn $ pwdOut 
    if not pathExists
       then do
         liftIO $ (cmd_ ("mkdir -p" :: String) [gitPath] :: IO ())
         liftIO $ (cmd_ ("cd" :: String) [gitPath] :: IO ())
         liftIO $ (cmd_ ("git init" :: String) :: IO ())
         return $ Settings { url = ""}
       else do
         liftIO $ (cmd_ (Cwd ".") ("cd" :: String) [gitPath] :: IO ())
         Stdout out <- liftIO $ (cmd ("git config --get remote.origin.url" :: String))
         return $ Settings {url = out}
```

It fails with an error `cd: createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)` in both cases: if dir exists and when `mkdir` command is executed.

Cannot wrap my head around it. But before I submit a bug to the shake's github page, I want to make sure with you I am not doing anything stupid that might cause this kind of behavior.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shake's [Haddock page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.19.6/docs/Development-Shake.html) describes [`cmd_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.19.6/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:cmd_), and links to its [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.19.6/docs/src/Development.Shake.Command.html#cmd_). There we can see that `cmd_` eventually calls [`commandExplicitIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.19.6/docs/src/Development.Shake.Command.html#commandExplicitIO), which constructs a [`ProcessOpts`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.19.6/docs/src/General.Process.html#ProcessOpts) with [`RawCommand`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.13.2/docs/System-Process.html#v:RawCommand) and passes it to [`process`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.19.6/docs/src/General.Process.html#process). `process` then takes that `ProcessOpts`, pattern-matches it as a `RawCommand` (via [`cmdSpec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.19.6/docs/src/General.Process.html#cmdSpec)), and calls [`proc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.13.2/docs/System-Process.html#v:proc). We have now entered the [well-documented zone](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.13.2/docs/System-Process.html#v:RawCommand): you must give `proc` an *executable*, and `cd` is not an executable. (Why? Since processes cannot change the working directory of their parent, `cd` must be a shell builtin.)

Comment: I think he needs to  do `cmd_ (Cwd gitPath)` after mkdir.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the other answer, `cd` is not an executable, so if you wanted to run it, you would have to pass `Shell` to `cmd`.

However, it is almost certainly the case that you don't want to call `cd` in a command, as it does *not* change the directory for any subsequent command. Each `cmd` is a separate process, with a separate environment, so the subsequent command will be in a fresh environment, and the same working directory as before the `cd`. The solution is to pass `(Cwd gitPath)` to each command you want to operate with the given directory.